# Its a JMeter Issue while making JDBC Connection

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Steps done for JDBC Connection are:
1) Thread > JDBC Request > JDBC Connection configuration.
2) Settings under JDBC Connection Configuration are
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=sa;integratedSecurity=true
username : SA
password : abc
JDBC Driver : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Placed the JDBC Driver in bin folder where JMeter is present.
also the dll files are placed in C:\program files\java and C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin

The error shown is **"Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.)"**
Please help in resolving this issue.
TIA

Comment: Remove `;integratedSecurity=true` as you seem to want to use SQL authentication, and not integrated authentication. Otherwise see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: It worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `sqljdbc_auth.dll` somewhere to [java.library.path](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/) and restart JMeter to pick the .dll up.

The `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file lives under `auth` folder of the [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) bundle.

As soon as you will have it under your `java.library.path` your problem should go away.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) article to learn more about database testing using JMeter

Comment: Hi. thanks. it worked after removal of ;integratedSecurity=true. from Database URL

Comment: My answer is about logging into SQL server using your machine credentials, if you need to use SQL authentication go the other way

Comment: Thank you Dmitri :)

Answer (score -1):

With the Help of @MarkRotteveel this problem has been solved.
I removed the ;integratedSecurity=true from Database URL.

Comment: this is actually not the windows authentication then, but sql server authentication...